# docker-compose run does not set environment variables

Tags: docker-compose

I do use docker-compose and have a `.env` file containing a environment variable:

```
KEY=VAL
```

Additionally I have the following in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    webapp:
     build: ./dir
     environment:
       - KEY={$KEY}
```

If I run `docker-compose build` as well as `docker-compose up` the environment variable KEY is accessable in the container.
If I now run some command: `docker-compose run webapp echo $KEY`

It prints nothing, so so guess it is not set. Is that normal behaviour, or do I miss something substantial?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For anyone having the same problem, there seems to be a problem with the echo command, which will print the $KEY of the host, not the container.

If I do 'docker-compose run webapp printenv' I do see my variable. So it really is available in the container.

If i do "docker-compose run webapp 'echo $KEY'" (single quotes around the echo $KEY) I get the following error:

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo $KEY\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: The echo problem seems to be related to alpine container image

Comment: I'm trying to use an env var to set the image tag with the same error (it seems that the env var is empty):
ERROR: no such image: myimage:: invalid reference format

To set the env var from command line: docker-compose run -e TAG=tagname myimage 

If I export TAG=tagname it works properly